# MMORPG creation and supporting software

Tags: gratis, game-development

I am looking for free MMORPG/MUD creation software that is simple to use or easy to learn.

Can anyone supply me with the tools to be able to do this?

Comment: Upvote, because I would like this too. BUT, auto-generated code will never have the flair of hand-crafted.

Comment: A framework/library for programming your game, or a tool (with GUI?) that allows creating the game without programming knowledge? On which operating system should the tool run? Any required features?

Comment: One of the biggest obstacles to "easy" game creation is complexity of media required. A game with complex renderings of 3D characters, realistic-looking terrain and items requires a large library of content which can be very expensive or time-consuming to create. So it would be good to know what level of sophistication you would be happy with in terms of display, and/or whether you'd be happy with a limited library of environments and game items.